# MongoDB - Update some records using data from a text/csv file

Tags: mongodb

I need to write a script to update an existing collection in mongodb using data from a text/csv file.

This file will have a set of id fields and its corresponding new field data.

The script should find the records in mongodb which have the ids from the file and then add the new field to the record with the corresponding value given in the file.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Resmi

Comment: Hi Resmi, it would greatly improve your chances of getting a correct answer if you could at least show what you've done to try to answer it yourself already. This is helpful in that you will likely receive feedback that will benefit your thought processes. The more you expose your thought process and reasoning the more other people can help you to build upon them for future problems.

Comment: You're best bet will be to convert the file contents to JSON and work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
// read data from file and split it by '\n', each line contains a data like `SomeName,SomeValue`
var file = cat('/data.csv');
var data = file.split('\n');

// check if we have such records
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var nameAndValue = data[i].split(',');
   printjson(db.YouDB.findOne({"name": nameAndValue[0]}));
}

// update records
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var nameAndValue = data[i].split(',');
    printjson(db.YouDB.update({"name": namesAndValue[0]}, {$set:{"value":nameAndValue[1]}}));
}
```